# How to determine the size of popen stream?

Tags: c, linux, popen

I want to determine the stream size retruned by the popen() function call. I tried to use fseek and ftell but it returns the size as -1. Can anyone suggest me how to determine the file size? The following is the code what I am using....

```
   char return_val[256];
FILE *fp = NULL;
char line[256];
memset (return_val, 0, 256);
/* set the defalut value */
strncpy (return_val, "N/A", 4);
char cmd[] = "if [ -f /etc/version ]; then cut -d, -f1 -s /etc/version ; fi";

/* Open the command for reading. */
fp = popen(cmd, "r");
if (fp != NULL) 
{
    /* read the line from file */
    fgets (line, 256, fp);
    if( line != NULL)
    {
            /* copy the data */
            strncpy(return_val, line, strnlen (line, 256)); 
        }
      /* close the file */ 
    pclose (fp);
}
```

Comment: First: using ftell/fseek to determine the size of a file is a total kludge.  Use a platform specific mechanism such as stat(2) instead.  Second, ftell is does not "return the size as -1".  It returns -1 to indicate that an error occurred.  Namely, that you are trying to call ftell on a file which is not a regular file.

Comment: @William: Thanks for your response. I think I can't use stat() here because popen() returns only pointer to the stream. stat() requires named file to check the properties. Yes, ftell() returns an -1 (error) because I am trying to access popen() stream which is not a regular file. Is there any work to determine the poopen() stream size?

Comment: What do you mean by the "stream size"?  How much water is in a river?  You can use fstat on the underlying file descriptor, but doing so is pointless if you want to get the size because the concept of size is not meaningful for a pipe.

Comment: @William: Thanks for the response. I have understood what you have said. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. popen gives you a pipe, a FIFO First In First Out stream. Characters go in on the one side and they come out at the other. It is in the nature of a pipe that you don't know in advance how many bytes there will be transmitted.

You may either resort to in band signalling, how many bytes there are to come, or you implement buffering and dynamic allocation on your side.

Also seeking is not possible on a pipe, because its merely a kind of "Portal" between those processes. You know, like in the game "Portal"/"Portal2".