# How to fseek() on a pipe

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for output of popen but trying to find the length of the file is giving "illegal seek" error. The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    char cmd[40] = {0};
    char * c;
    int byteCount = 0;
    FILE * pFp = NULL;
    strncpy(cmd, "ls -l", sizeof(cmd));
    pFp =  popen(cmd, "r");
    if (pFp == NULL)
        printf ("file is null");
    fseek(pFp, 0, SEEK_END);
    byteCount = ftell(pFp);
    perror("seek ");
    fclose(pFp);
}
```

fgets works fine, are there any constraints in using fseek with popen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Comment: `popen(cmd, "r");` , what is this?

Comment: @haccks That's a function call.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unreadable.


Comment: you cannot do this also refer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975170/how-to-determine-the-size-of-popen-stream

Comment: You're essentially saying "Let me have back the water that flowed through here a while ago". Which you can't - it flowed through and is now gone, unless you placed that water in some buckets you can go back to instead of the pipe.

Comment: edited the code for readability, hoping it helps. Thanks for the link @Bose

Answer (score 17):

Yes you can't seek backwards from a pipe, only forwards. A pipe in the computer is just like a pipe in real life, the data flows only in one direction, and you can't change the flow.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was considering the output to be a file rather than a pipe.